# Simple bash script; what's wrong with this syntax?

Tags: bash

I'm reading bash script tutorials and this seems like it should work, but I clearly am missing something:

```
isframecount=0
framecount=0
while read p; do
  if ["$isframecount" -eq 0]
    then 
    echo $p
    $isframecount = 1
    else
    echo "frame count"
    echo $p
    $isframecount = 0
  fi
done < $filenam
```

I get "command not found errors" when I try to run the above; any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch out for spaces where they matters and where there should be not. In this case, `if ["$isframecount" -eq 0]` should be `if [ "$isframecount" -eq 0 ]` (see the spaces after `[` and before `]`).

The reason for this is that `[` is actually the name of a program... See by yourself... Type `ls /bin/[`... Now, if there is no space, then bash will look for a program named `["0"` or something similar, which most certainly does not exist in your path.

Then, the opposite situation...  There must be no space around the `=` in variable assignment. So `$isframecount = 1` should be `isframecount=1`. Note that I also removed the dollar sign, that's the way to go.

Comment: +1 Minor note: `bash` implements `[` as a builtin rather than using `/bin/[`.

Comment: @chepner Right, Bash offer built-in alternatives to several traditional external executables. This is however only an optimization to reduce process forking. People learning bash need not think about this, it only gets more confusing.

Answer (score 2):

```
if [ "$isframecount" -eq 0 ]
```

Spaces are required on both sides of the square brackets.

```
isframecount=1
```

No dollar sign, no spaces around `=` in an assignment statement.

Comment: so the dollar sign is for reading, and without it is for writing?

Answer (score 2):

**Two issues:**

**Issue 1:**

You need to have spaces in `test` operator. Change the following line:

```
if ["$isframecount" -eq 0]
```

to

```
if [ "$isframecount" -eq 0 ]
```

**Issue 2:**

`$isframecount = 1`

There should be no `$` sign before variable and no spaces in the assignment operator

Change it to `isframecount=1`

Comment: Also, as a general rule of thumb, quote your variables!!